# I need to provide a duotone pdf, what do I need to do with my figures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, asymptote

I need to provide a duotone pdf (say black and cyan). My figures are made with tikz, pgfplots and asymptote (3D but no prc), some with opacity effects. I compile with pdftex and luatex.

1. What do I have to do so that it works smoothly? I can think of defining new cycle list for pgfplots and, of course, not using blue or red in tikz or in asymptote. Is there something else? Will opacity work?
2. What kind of colors can I use? How can I define them with xcolors? What rationale do one use to name those colors?
3. Regarding color pictures. Do I need to convert them outside of TeX or is there a way to do it from TeX?

Comment: Would `\selectcolormodel{gray}` from `xcolor` package be sufficient?

Comment: @percusse I may be wrong here but I think that the gray color model is monotone (only black).

Comment: Oops, so you want to blend black and cyan? Or better, say you have red in the document now what kind of mechanism do you have in mind?

Comment: @percusse I have no color in my document yet. I just want to make the right decisions regarding color definition. Yes: I can blend black and cyan.

Comment: Concerning pgfplots: if you use any code which relies on `colormap`s (like `scatter` or `surf` or `contour` variants), you may want to (a) use a suitable `colormap` and (b) ensure that you have the correct colorspace. Default is RGB, but you can also use `colormap default colorspace=cmyk` (applies only to newly generated colormaps, compare manual). Sounds as if CMYK might be a good choice here to simplify interpolation between black and cyan (?)

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, the most efficient way seems to use only user defined colors, within the cmyk color space (affecting `0` to both magenta and yellow channels).

For example, here are the definitions of the colors I used in my project.

```
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\providecolor{PureDuotone}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}
\providecolor{DarkDuotone}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0.4}
\providecolor{LightDuotone}{cmyk}{.3,0,0,.3}
\providecolor{PaleDuotone}{cmyk}{0.1,0,0,0}
\providecolor{LightGray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.10}
\providecolor{Gray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.15}
\providecolor{DarkGray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.25}
\providecolor{VeryDarkGray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.4}
\providecolor{UltraDarkGray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.6}
```

For `pgfplots`, I used the following (I'm stuck to version 1.8).

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{%
  colormap default colorspace = cmyk,
  colormap = {duotone}{cmyk(0cm)=(1,0,0,.4); cmyk(1cm)=(.4,0,0,1)}}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{duotonelinestyles*}{%
  {%
    solid,
    color = DarkDuotone,
    thick,
  },
  {%
    solid,
    color = black,
    thick,
  },
  {%
    solid,
    color = VeryDarkGray,
    thick,
  },
  {%
    dashed,
    color = DarkDuotone,
    thick,
  },
  {%
    dashed,
    color = black,
    thick,
  },
  {%
    dashed,
    color = VeryDarkGray,
    thick,
  }}
```

I suggest to call `xcolor` before all `tikz` related package with the option `cmyk`.

Unfortunately, it does not solve all issues: patterns and shadings in `tikz` are hard coded in the `RGB` colorspace in the resulting `pdf` file (*even they are defined in terms of `cmyk` colors*). [A workaround is possible with patterns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149144/8425), but, at the time of writing, there is no equivalent for shadings that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

For asymptote figures, the cmyk command-line switch `-cmyk` may help, provided colors are defined in terms of cmyk pens inside the asy source. For some figures, I needed to use imagemagick's `convert`. Here is a little script that I found useful.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(find -name "*.asy")
  do  asy -render 5 -cmyk -noV -noprc $i -o ${i%asy}eps
      convert -colorspace cmyk -channel c -fx 'c-y' -channel k -fx 'k+m' -channel y -fx '0' -channel m -fx '0' -density 300 -geometry 50%x eps:"${i%asy}eps" jpg:"${i%asy}jpg"
done
```